# How could i display multiple elements when hovering another

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to figure out how i can set display:block; on all the p tags and on the overlay div when im hovering my img tag. Is this possible only with CSS or would i have to figure something out with javascript. Or should i change the way i approach this? All help is appreciated thanks.

```css
.staff-pic-contain {
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.staff-pic {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

p {
  font-weight: bold;
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
  display: none;
}

.name {
  margin-top: 15%;
}

.number {
  margin-top: 25%;
}

.overlay {
  background-color: red;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  opacity: 0.75;
  display: none;
}

img:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="staff-pic-contain">
  <img class="staff-pic" src="https://picsum.photos/g/200/300" alt="">
  <p class="position"> CEO </p>
  <p class="name"> NAME </p>
  <p class="number"> 123123 </p>
  <div class="overlay"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: should be possible with :hover pseudo class, read it online, javascript is also good and browser safe option

Answer (score 2):

Use CSS to display the `p` and `.overlay` when hovering the container:

```
.staff-pic-contain:hover p, .staff-pic-contain:hover .overlay {
  display: block;
}
```

To limit the hover area to the image, add `border-radius: 50%` to the container.

Demo:

```css
.staff-pic-contain {
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.staff-pic {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

p {
  font-weight: bold;
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
  display: none;
}

.name {
  margin-top: 15%;
}

.number {
  margin-top: 25%;
}

.overlay {
  background-color: red;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  opacity: 0.75;
  display: none;
}

img:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.staff-pic-contain:hover p, .staff-pic-contain:hover .overlay {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="staff-pic-contain">
  <img class="staff-pic" src="https://picsum.photos/g/200/300" alt="">
  <p class="position"> CEO </p>
  <p class="name"> NAME </p>
  <p class="number"> 123123 </p>
  <div class="overlay"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, `~` will not work well in this case.

Comment: I wonder why take the time answering such trivial questions when it's obvious that the OP is lazy enough not to google it and spent half hour..

Comment: @OriDrori This i already knew, what im trying not to do is make it possible to hover outside the image circle. As you see the overlay and text appears when hovering just outside the image circle.

Comment: @user9294038 add: .staff-pic-contain {border-radius: 50%}

Comment: @user9294038 this info need to be clear in your question, we are not mind reader ...

Comment: @user9294038 - this was not apparent from your question. VXp's idea is the way to go - see updated answer.